# How to create dependent dropdown custom field in wordpress admin post form

Tags: wp-admin, dropdown

I want to create state and city dependent dropdown custom field in WordPress admin post form. So what approach I should follow ? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

If the form is in post edit, I'll probably enqueue a script for my dropdown on edit page, and I'll use metabox to add a form un WordPress post edit.

[Metabox Documentation on WP Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/)